# Create Sql Trigger Query syntax issue

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have created a trigger, If I create it manually, its working, when I export and run the query in another database, showing syntax error near If condition. Can anyone help, what is the issue in the below query

```
CREATE TRIGGER advance_audit 
AFTER UPDATE ON employee 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
IF NEW.firstname <> OLD.firstname THEN 
    INSERT INTO employees_audit (action, column_name, old_name, new_name, operator)
    VALUES ('update', 'firstname', OLD.firstname, NEW.firstname, SYSTEM_USER());
END IF;
IF NEW.lastname <> OLD.lastname THEN 
    INSERT INTO employees_audit (action, column_name, old_name, new_name, operator)
    VALUES ('update', 'lastname', OLD.lastname, NEW.lastname, SYSTEM_USER());
END IF;

END
```

Comment: *when I export and run the query in another database, showing syntax error near If condition.* (1) Always proivide complete error message while reporting about error. (2) Have you defined custom DELIMITER during trigger creation?

Comment: You have have an error in sql syntax near ' '  at line 5.
@Akina I have tried using delimeter, but showing other error after adding it.

Comment: *but showing other error after adding it.* Read remark (1).

Answer (score 0):

Convert your trigger to single-statement form:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER advance_audit 
AFTER UPDATE ON employee 
FOR EACH ROW 
INSERT INTO employees_audit (action, column_name, old_name, new_name, operator)
    SELECT 'update', 'firstname', NEW.firstname, OLD.firstname, SYSTEM_USER() 
    WHERE NEW.firstname <> OLD.firstname
  UNION ALL
    SELECT 'update', 'lastname', NEW.lastname, OLD.lastname, SYSTEM_USER() 
    WHERE NEW.lastname <> OLD.lastname;
```

Comment: I tried to run my query with delimiter in live server, Below issue is showing

#1419 - You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)

Can you please tell me what I have to do.

Comment: @Sonu I don't understand the relation between my answer and your comment to it...